# Proving all eigenvalues of $A+B$ and $A-B$ are real.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ and $B$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices. Eigenvalues of $A$ are $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$ and eigenvalues of B are $\frac{1}{x_1}$,$\frac{1}{x_2}$,$\frac{1}{x_3}$,$\frac{1}{x_4}$, where each $x_i > 1$.

I need to prove the following

1. $A+B$ has at least one eigenvalue greater than 2
2. $A-B$ has at least one eigenvalue greater than 0

My attempt:

1. $trace(A+B)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{i=4}(x_i+\frac{1}{x_i}) > 8$. Hence if all of the eigenvalues of A are real, we are done with the proof.
2. $trace(A-B)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{i=4}(x_i-\frac{1}{x_i}) > 0$ as $x_i  > 1$. Hence if all of the eigenvalues of A are real, we are done with the proof.

Both of my proofs need the fact that all eigenvalues of $A+B$ and $A-B$ are real. I couldn't prove this fact.

Comment: I see, sorry. I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true. Here is a random counterexample. Consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(2,3,4,5)$ and $B=PA^{-1}P^{-1}$ where
$$
P=\pmatrix{0&1&1&1+i\\ i&i&i&1+i\\ 1+i&1&0&i\\ i&0&1&0}.
$$
You may use a computer algebra package to verify that none of the eigenvalues of $A+B$ or $A-B$ is real.